# JavaMail: MailBox sempre baixa os mesmos email

Tags: java, javamail

Estou baixando os emails do *Gmail*, e guardando no banco de dados os que são importantes para o sistema do meu cliente.

Só que o problema está quando uso o código abaixo, ele sempre me retorna os mesmos emails, ficando em duplicidade.

Alguém já passou por isso?

### Código:

```
try {
    System.out.println("asdasdasd");
    // create properties field
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
    properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
    Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
    Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

    store.connect(host, user, password);

    // create the folder object and open it
    Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
    System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

    for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
        Message message = messages[i];
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
        System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
        System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
        System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
        System.out.println(message.getLineCount());

    }

    // close the store and folder objects
    emailFolder.close(false);
    store.close();

} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Já tentou o laço dessa forma: `for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)` ??

Answer (score 0):

Quando vc executa `Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();` ele retorna TODAS as mensagens do folder, que no seu caso é o INBOX, é por isso que ele sempre trás as mesmas mensagens.

Você pode resolver o problema aplicando um filtro (Não lidas por exemplo) no resgate das mensagens, deletando as mensagens do folder ou movendo para outra pasta, por exemplo:

**Aplicando um filtro no resgate das mensagens:**
Altere `Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();` por:

```
// O filtro aqui são as mensagens não visualizadas ainda
FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
Message messages[] = inbox.search(ft);
```

**Deletando as mensagens do folder**

```
Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
    Message message = messages[i];
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
    System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
    System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
    System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
    System.out.println(message.getLineCount());
}

// close the store and folder objects
emailFolder.setFlags(messages, new Flags(Flags.Flag.DELETED), true);
emailFolder.close(true);
store.close();
```

**Movendo para outra pasta:**

```
Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
Folder folderDestino = store.getFolder("PASTA DE DESTINO");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
folderDestino.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
    Message message = messages[i];
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
    System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
    System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
    System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
    System.out.println(message.getLineCount());
}

// close the store and folder objects
emailFolder.copyMessages(messages, folderDestino);
emailFolder.setFlags(messages, new Flags(Flags.Flag.DELETED), true);

emailFolder.close(true);
folderDestino.close(true);
store.close();
```

Ainda existe a possibilidade de vc determinar o início e o fim das mensagens que serão capturadas no método `getMessages` mas acredito que esta solução seja muito ruim.